# Cannot run MapReduce with azure blob storage (WASB)

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, wasabi

We are trying to run smoke test mapreduce job from hadoop examples (terasort):

```
[hdfs@xxxxx 2.2.0.0-2041]$ hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar teragen 100 /test/10gsort/input
```

We are dealing with following problems:

```
16/01/26 12:52:27 INFO mapreduce.Cluster: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider due to error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class  org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb not found 
java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1262)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.terasort.TeraGen.run(TeraGen.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.terasort.TeraGen.main(TeraGen.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!
We are using this jar:

```
microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar -> /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar
```

Comment: It seems the JAR file for WASB (I think `hadoop-azure.jar`) is in not in your CLASSPATH

Comment: Thanks, that could help.